# How to process a CSV file using Reactor Flux and output as JSON

Tags: spring, flux, reactor

I've got a CSV file which I want to process using Spring Reactor Flux.

> Given a CSV file with header where first two columns are fixed, and
>   can have more then one optional data columns

```
Id, Name, Group, Status
6EF3C06E-6240-1A4A-17D6-27E73F0CDD31, Harlan Ferguson, xy1, true
6B261437-217C-0FDF-741A-92477EE354EC, Risa Greene, xy2, false
4FADC070-FCD0-C7E8-1963-A7FACDB6D8D1, Samson Blanchard, xy3, false
562C3486-E009-2C2D-9D3E-14355DB7D4D7, Damian Carson, xy4, true
...
...
...
```

> I want to process the input using Flux
>   So that the output is

```
[{
    "Id": "6EF3C06E-6240-1A4A-17D6-27E73F0CDD31",
    "Name": "Harlan Ferguson",
    "data": {
        "Group": "xyz1",
        "Status": true
    }
}, {
    "Id": "6B261437-217C-0FDF-741A-92477EE354EC",
    "Name": "Risa Greene",
    "data": {
        "Group": "xy2",
        "Status": false
    }
}, {
    "Id": "4FADC070-FCD0-C7E8-1963-A7FACDB6D8D1",
    "Name": "Samson Blanchard",
    "data": {
        "Group": "xy3",
        "Status": false
    }
}, {
    "Id": "562C3486-E009-2C2D-9D3E-14355DB7D4D7",
    "Name": "Damian Carson",
    "data": {
        "Group": "xy4",
        "Status": true
    }
}]
```

I'm using CSVReader to stream and creating and Flux using

```
new CSVReader( Files.newBufferedReader(file) );
Flux<String[]> fluxOfCsvRecords = Flux.fromIterable(reader);
```

*I'm coming back to Spring Reactor after couple of years, so my understanding is a bit rusty.*

Creating a Mono of header using

```
Mono<String[]> headerMono = fluxOfCsvRecords.next();
```

And then,

```
fluxOfCsvRecords.skip(1)
  .flatMap(csvRecord -> headerMono.map(header -> header[0] + " : " + csvRecord[0]))
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This is half-way code just to test that I'm able to combine data from header and rest of the flux, expecting to see

```
Id : 6EF3C06E-6240-1A4A-17D6-27E73F0CDD31
Id : 6B261437-217C-0FDF-741A-92477EE354EC
Id : 4FADC070-FCD0-C7E8-1963-A7FACDB6D8D1
Id : 562C3486-E009-2C2D-9D3E-14355DB7D4D7
```

But my output is just

```
4FADC070-FCD0-C7E8-1963-A7FACDB6D8D1 : 6EF3C06E-6240-1A4A-17D6-27E73F0CDD31
```

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me understand how to achieve this.

---------------------------Update---------------------

Tried another approach

```
Flux<String[]> take1 = fluxOfCsvRecords.take(1);
take1.flatMap(header -> fluxOfCsvRecords.map(csvRecord -> header[0] + " : " + csvRecord[0]))
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The output is

```
Id : 6B261437-217C-0FDF-741A-92477EE354EC
Id : 4FADC070-FCD0-C7E8-1963-A7FACDB6D8D1
Id : 562C3486-E009-2C2D-9D3E-14355DB7D4D7
```

Missing the row after the header

Answer (score 0):

Add Two class like

```
public class TopJson {
    private int Id;
    private String name;

    private InnerJson data;

    public TopJson() {}
    public TopJson(int id, String name, InnerJson data) {
        super();
        Id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }



}


class InnerJson{

    private String group;
    private String status;
    public InnerJson() {}
    public InnerJson(String group, String status) {
        super();
        this.group = group;
        this.status = status;
    }
```

***converted to appropriate types and used to create the object.***

```
fluxOfCsvRecords.skip(1)
      .map((Function<String, TopJson>) x -> {
            String[] csvRecord = line.split(",");// a CSV has comma separated lines
            return new TopJson(Integer.parseInt(csvRecord[0]), csvRecord[1],
                    new InnerJson(csvRecord[2], csvRecord[3]));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Hi Harkesh, Thanks for posting the reply. The snippet isn't working as there is a compilation error. But after a quick look at the code, it seems you're ignoring the CSV header. For a fixed CSV schema, this may work but there are optional columns where the header can be anything - hence I'm capturing them inside the data field. I hope this clarifies the requirement.

Comment: wait i am not skipping header